# syntax error unexpected token ")"

Tags: javascript, safari

Safari ругается на эту часть кода `container.addEventListener('click', () => {`

Выскакивает ошибка `syntax error unexpected token ")"` Подскажите пожалуйста как исправить ее.

```js
const container = document.getElementById('container');
const table = document.getElementById('table');
const target = document.getElementById('target');
document.body.style.setProperty('--main-color', '#FFFFFF');
document.body.style.setProperty('--glav-color', '#09406f');
container.addEventListener('click', () => {
    target.classList.toggle('toggle');
    target.classList.toggle('sun');
    target.classList.toggle('moon');

    if (getComputedStyle(document.body).getPropertyValue('--main-color') == '#FFFFFF') {
        document.body.style.setProperty('--responsiv-color', 'none');
        document.body.style.setProperty('--responsiv-fontColor', 'beige');
        document.body.style.setProperty('--table-color', '#000000');
        document.body.style.setProperty('--glav-color', '#1C293E');
        document.body.style.setProperty('--h2-fontColor', '#fff');
        document.body.style.setProperty('--main-color', '#231C36');
        document.body.style.setProperty('--tbody-fontColor', '#FFAE46');
        document.body.style.setProperty('--tdhover-fontColor', '#fff');
        document.body.style.setProperty('--trhover-fontColor', '#fff');
        document.body.style.setProperty('--blackwhite-fontColor', '#fff');

    } else if (getComputedStyle(document.body).getPropertyValue('--main-color') == '#231C36') {
        document.body.style.setProperty('--responsiv-fontColor', '#000');
        document.body.style.setProperty('--responsiv-color', '#ffffff');
        document.body.style.setProperty('--tbody-fontColor', '#000');
        document.body.style.setProperty('--glav-color', '#09406f');
        document.body.style.setProperty('--h2-fontColor', '#030303!important');
        document.body.style.setProperty('--table-color', '#FFFFFF');
        document.body.style.setProperty('--main-color', '#FFFFFF');
        document.body.style.setProperty('--tdhover-fontColor', '#000');
        document.body.style.setProperty('--trhover-fontColor', '#000');
        document.body.style.setProperty('--blackwhite-fontColor', '#000');
    }
});
```

```css
html, body {--main-color: #FFFFFF;--table-color: #FFFFFF;width: 100%;justify-content: center;align-items: center;background-color: var(--main-color);transition: background-color .3s ease-in-out;}.table-responsive h2 {color: var(--responsiv-fontColor)!important;}.table-responsive {background: var(--responsiv-color)!important;}#container {border-radius: 25px;height: 30px;width: 80px;background-color: var(--main-color);cursor: pointer;transition: all .3s ease-in-out;box-shadow: 0px 0px 15pxrgba(0, 0, 0, .15);margin: 0px auto;z-index: 999999;position: relative;top: 10px;}table {background-color: var(--table-color);color: var(--tbody-fontColor);}tbody {background-color: var(--table-color);color: var(--tbody-fontColor);}td:hover, tr:hover {color: var(--tdhover-fontColor)!important;}table.dataTable.display tr:hover {color: var(--blackwhite-fontColor)!important;}tr:hover .sorting_1:hover {background-color: var(--table-color);color: var(--trhover-fontColor);}table.dataTable.display tbody tr.odd: {var(--table-color)!important;color: var(--tbody-fontColor)!important;color: black!important;}#target {position: relative;left: 0px;transition: all .3s ease-in-out;bottom: 18px;}.toggle {left: calc(100% - 50px) !important;}.sun {cursor: pointer;width: 30px;height: 30px;border-radius: 50%;background-color: #FFDB73;}.sun::before {content: '';position: absolute;top: 50%;left: 50%;transform: translate(-50%, -50%);width: 30px;height: 30px;border-radius: 50%;background-color: #FFDB73;}.sun::after {content: '';position: absolute;top: 50%;left: 50%;transform: translate(-50%, -50%);width: 55px;height: 55px;border-radius: 50%;background-color: #FFDB73;opacity: .3;}.table-responsive::after {background: #000!important;border-top: 1px solid#fff!important;color: white;width: 100%!important;}.moon {cursor: pointer;width: 50px;height: 50px;border-radius: 50%;background-color: #0A515B;position: relative;z-index: 999999999;}.moon::before {content: '';position: absolute;top: 50%;left: 50%;transform: translate(-50%, -50%);width: 60px;height: 60px;border-radius: 50%;background-color: #0A515B;opacity: .5;}.moon::after {content: '';position: absolute;top: 50%;left: 50%;transform: translate(-50%, -50%);width: 75px;height: 75px;border-radius: 50%;background-color: #0A515B;opacity: .3;}.moon > div {position: relative;width: 100%;height: 100%;}.moon > div::before {content: '';position: absolute;top: 50%;left: 50%;transform: translate(-50%, -50%);width: 25px;height: 25px;border-radius: 50%;background-color: #FFE4BF;z-index: 1;}.moon > div::after {content: '';position: absolute;top: 10px;right: 10px;width: 20px;height: 20px;border-radius: 50%;background-color: #0A515B;z-index: 2;}#zagolovok {color: var(--h2-fontColor);}.jumbotron {background-color: var(--glav-color);}#container::before {content: "";position: relative;left: 50px;width: 18px;height: 18px;display: block;background: url(/sun1.webp) no-repeat;top: 5px;right: 0px;z-index: 99999999;bottom: 0px;}#container::after {content: "\2606";position: relative;left: 10px;right: 50px;width: 12px;height: 20px;display: block;bottom: 75px;color: white;overflow: hidden;}.mewtwo-datepicker td {color: black!important;}table.dataTable.display tbody tr.odd: {var(--table-color)!important;color: var(--tbody-fontColor)!important;}table {background-color: var(--table-color);color: var(--tbody-fontColor);}tbody, tr {background-color: var(--table-color)!important;color: var(--tbody-fontColor)!important;}tr:hover {background-color: var(--table-color);color: var(--tbody-fontColor);}
```

```html
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<div id='container'>
    <div id='target' class='sun'>
     <div></div>
```

Comment: может лямбду не пережевал? какой то древний сафари? прикольный toggle

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Вроде не древний

Comment: мой iphone se все показал как надо

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Можно Вас попросить показать screen моего сайта avia-avia.ru как он у вас на айфоне виден, а то может что с браузером у меня? Заранее спасибо

Comment: https://ibb.co/5WHz4j2

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Спасибо и ночной режим работает?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Спасибо Вам!

Comment: переключалка срабатывает

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Спасибо, а фон сам, стили меняются?

Comment: да, стили меняются

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Спасибо, значит в браузере дело

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
container.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
```

Comment: Ошибка исправилась, но изменений по цвету почему -то не происходит

Comment: @Arcadiy Подозреваю, что теперь дело в `classList`.

Comment: @Arcadiy https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#Browser_compatibility

Comment: что с ним нужно сделать? "classList"

Comment: @Arcadiy Я не уверен, что дело именно в нем. Надо разбираться, что не поддерживается Вашим браузером.